# JavaFX Spinner : "Spinner cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, eclipse, spinner, efxclipse

All other classes from JavaFX work fine but Spinner gives me `"Spinner cannot be resolved to a type"`.

I also tried to import `import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;` but this gaves me `The import javafx.scene.control.Spinner cannot be resolved`back.

My current import list which WORKS fine :

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
```

Someone can help ? I also downloaded e(fx)lipse to solve it but didnt helped

Comment: What JDK are you using? javafx.scene.control.Spinner is the correct class name. Try cleaning and building again, with that import in place. Change * to Spinner and see what else it throws up. It must be a different control that's causing the issue.

Comment: I tried to clean it but didnt helped. 'import javafx.scene.control.*;' throws me nothing back but says that im never using the import. And Spinner is still redlined with '"Spinner cannot be resolved to a type"'

Comment: Note that Spinner was added in 8u40.

Comment: Oh I got JDK 8u30 ... Thats it I guess. Can I use Spinner without install a new SDK ?

Comment: No, you cannot Ahmet, you need to use the 8u40 runtime as a minimum.

Comment: Okay then. Thanks for your help guys ! Somebody who wants to write an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: I had the same thing happen to me first time I tried using `Alert`. As pointed out, if you upgrade to the latest JDK it should be fine. (also make sure your project is set to use said version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arjan noted in the comments, check the precise Java version you are using - it is probably lower than 8u40 in which the Spinner was added - and update your JDK.

As a side note: I ran into this when using Travis CI, from [their issue tracker](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3259) we know that at the moment the fix is to add `dist: trusty` to the `.travis.yml` file, but hopefully they update eventually.